# Android Range SeekBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

How to implement a dual selection seek bar?
Need to get a range from user input.

Kindly give suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/range-seekbar/

Comment: @SMR This is the link: [link] (http://blog.jquerymobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jqm_range-sliders.png)

Comment: All right I think others have already given answer to for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check these two libraries as they provide what you are looking for :

1. [DoubleSeekBar](https://github.com/joaocsousa/DoubleSeekBar)
2. [range-seek-bar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)

and please give me some feedback

Hope that Helps .

Comment: Range-seek-bar is good, thx.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for, a range seekbar selector.

[range-seek-bar link](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use or rework [this](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) or [this](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar) open source implementations.